# OpenCV iOS video recording memory leak

Tags: ios, opencv, memory-leaks

I posted this on answers.opencv.org but the response has been sluggish so I am hoping someone on here can help me out.

There is a tremendous memory leak in the CvVideoCamera object for iOS when you set the video camera to record. This issue has been brought up before and was even **resolved for the last version** according to [this](http://code.opencv.org/issues/3620). However, when using the latest framework and implementing like so....

```
//ViewController header (note I am not including all the importing that happens before this)
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<CvVideoCameraDelegate>
{
    ....
    IBOutlet UIImageView*imageView; //image view used for video feed
    CvVideoCamera*videoCamera; //OpenCV video camera
}
@property (retain, nonatomic) CvVideoCamera*videoCamera;
//end header file


//ViewController implementation file (compiled as .mm aka objective-c++)
@interface ViewController()
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize videoCamera;

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    ....

    //OpenCV Camera setup
    self.videoCamera=[[CvVideoCamera alloc] initWithParentView:imageView];
    self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureDevicePosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionBack; //select camera
    self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureSessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset352x288; //set resolution
    self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureVideoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait; //set orientation
    self.videoCamera.recordVideo = YES; //set record video to YES to record video
    self.videoCamera.defaultFPS = 30; //default frames per second
    self.videoCamera.grayscaleMode = NO; //grayscale mode
    self.videoCamera.delegate = self; //set up delegate

   ....
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
-(void)processImage(cv::Mat&)image
{
   //do some open cv stuff
   //for example
   cvtColor(image, image, CV_BGR2GRAY);
}
#endif
```

iOS kills the app after about 20-30 seconds of recording due to memory pressure. I understand that iOS has an aggressive kernel but it never gives me problems unless I record the video. Please note that I have not included all the code. There are some other things you have to do in order to properly record the video. And also I learned how to implement OpenCV in iOS using Instant OpenCV for iOS and this is covered in that book. I have investigated the issue using instruments from what I have experienced, this only happens when I set the record property to YES. Otherwise, we're all good. Now I have also seen [this post](http://answers.opencv.org/question/22880/cvvideocamera-on-ios7/). But I am not up for editing OpenCV source code because I will not want to do this every time OpenCV updates their framework. But I need to find a way to resolve this issue as soon as possible and I would greatly appreciate any help that people are willing to provide.

Answer (score -1):

I wonder if you get any solution.  I am encountering a slightly different problem and most of the leak happens during recording.

For your problem, you can fork opencv, and make changes to the file.  Then you can pull in changes from OpenCV as needed.

Comment: I just fixed this issue in here.  https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/pull/3986.  Hope it helps.